# Alexa cannot parse VF expressions results?

Tags: visualforce, seo

I have a force.com site which shows data pulled from custom objects. Site users' have `read` access to all the fields of all the objects used on this site. When I visit this site I can see all the data perfectly.

I am testing its SEO with Alexa. In one of the pages I have this code:

```
<title> {!position.Name} </title> 
//position.name is not empty
//position is an instance of a custom object populated in apex class. 
//site user can access position.Name
```

The Alexa analysis tool shows output for above line as: `<title> </title>`.

When I change code to this:

```
<title>{!orgName}</title>
//orgName is a string variable populated in apex class
```

The Alexa tool shows correct output as : `<title>My Organization</title>`

Anyone out there who have used Alexa with force.com sites and experience this behavior?

Comment: Turns out that this was a bug in Alexa. Their support replied that they have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
{!position.Name}
```

evaluates to an empty string.

As to why, we are going to need a lot more information to determine that